# Adding folder hierarchy to an existing .net project using VS 2010 custom templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, itemtemplate

I have one big .net (C#) project containing many small applications. This is the design the company has:

```
Main.Transport
 + Properties
 + References
 + ASD
 - Customer
   + Css
   - Js
     customer.js
   + Images
   - Support
     CustBroker.cs
     CustProvider.cs
   CustHandler.ashx
   Default.aspx
 - Order
   + Css
   - Js
     order.js
   + Images
   - Support
     OrderBroker.cs
     OrderProvider.cs
   OrderHandler.ashx
   Default.aspx
```

Whenever we have to develop more applications, I have to follow the same steps:

```
- Create a new folder
- Add subfolders
- Add some images, configs, css, js etc
- Add broker and provider classes
- Add handler and default page to the main folder (app)
```

I am not sure if we can create some custom templates in Visual Studio 2010 to speed up my setup and coding process. Can this be done by creating Items template or any other way? Any suggestions and links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you could crate a bash script that well do some things as adding folders and coping images automatically. 
for more details, see [a beginners tutorial for bash scripting](http://www.howtogeek.com/67469/the-beginners-guide-to-shell-scripting-the-basics/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I never did this before but surely go through the link and see if it helps. I wish, I could create templates for ease :)